# Is there a PCB coplanar edge connector made for high power transmission instead of data transmission?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

Looking for a PCB-to-PCB coplanar edge connector that can carry ideally 40V and 30A.

Comment: There are so many connectors out there. My suggestion is try one or two companies that have parametric search functions, or call one of the companies to get help from a sales person (if you work for a company they will probably help you).

Comment: 30A requires a substantial size conductor.  I think in most cases it is better to use wires than a board to deliver high currents, so if a board required a 40V and 30A power supply, that supply would be connected directly with substantial size wires rather than circuit board traces.  Please search "the xy problem" on meta stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

It is not unusual to use edge connectors to distribute high current. For example there are a few plug-in server power supplies used on HP server that do just that. The DPS-800 PS can kick out over 80A on an edge connector, but the trick they use is that the current is distributed over a large number of contacts. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186584/converting-a-dps800-server-psu-into-a-standalone-12v-psu) article for an insight.

There are also some connectors that can offer up to 40A per contact such as the [Molex Bus Bar Socket, Extreme PowerEdge](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=extreme_poweredge_&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction), or the [Hirose PS4 series](https://www.hirose.com/product/en/products/PS4/), which can deliver up to 300A per contact